# ObjectMapping java.util.Date to MongoDB "{ "time": ISODate() }" (MongoDB Java Driver + Jackson)

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I have the following code to insert products in MongoDB:

```
// This is just one product, but Im' looping several
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
builder.insert( (DBObject)JSON.parse(om.writeValueAsString(product)) );
BulkWriteResult result = builder.execute();
```

In the database, the field `private Date createdTime` becomes this JSON representation: `"createdTime" : 1418219627000` (Int64). In other words, milliseconds since epoc.

What I'm looking for is to map it to `"createdTime" : ISODate("1970-01-15T06:56:07.890Z")` in MongoDB. So, ISODate() or Date() whatever is more appropiate (versions etc).

What would be an approach to accomplish this? Using Java 8, so maybe some other type than Date() is in order?

Comment: Have not yet found a (neat) solution for this, using Java MongoDB Driver and create objects out of using constructors and get-methods for persisting, instead. Maintenance hungry code though.

Comment: @mmx73 I'm glad you provided the correct answer after your link was deleted. I did not delete it. It was marked as "link-only" by another reviewer. I argued against that designation, but it seems my argument was overruled.

Comment: @mmx73 It would be helpful to critique the accepted answer on that other question as well, so that others who find it will know which answer actually works. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @mmx73 BTW, you only need 15 rep to flag a question as a duplicate. You're way past that level. :-)

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom : now its closed anyway . i had a quite well documented and complete answer ready to post ... thats bad luck now its gone. The point is, this question is not the duplicate but the other one is because this question was asked prior. That pixxes me off a bit, i improved the other question so that there is a complete answer and I put the correct answer in here and the only thing I got is a down vote and a deleted answer. Thats not motivating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save object as a Date format, it will save into the mongoDB as a ISoDate, to be able to convert to again Date format you can use Jodatime library or some new date functions inside Java 8

Comment: What do you mean "saving as a Date format"? I am mapping from the `Date` type with the Object Mapper, but it converts it to an integer field.

Comment: When i use spring-data mongodb inside the @Document element i kept attribute as a Date format, send it to database without any manupulation, so it automatically can keeps ISADate format, Mongodb java driver can convert it.